# C# instantiate generic List from reflected Type

Tags: c#, reflection, generics

Is it possible to create a generic object from a reflected type in C# (.Net 2.0)?

```
void foobar(Type t){
    IList<t> newList = new List<t>(); //this doesn't work
    //...
}
```

The Type, t, is not known until runtime.

Comment: What do you expect to do with a list you don't know the type of at compile-time?

Comment: Are you able to write this as a generic function, as in `void foobar<T>() { IList<T> newList = new List<T>(); }`

Comment: I've a feeling this might be a code smell, as a result of tackling a larger problem in a bad way.

Comment: I posted a separate question regarding the larger problem at hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661734/c-using-generic-method-with-type

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Try this:

```
void foobar(Type t)
{
    var listType = typeof(List<>);
    var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(t);

    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
}
```

Now what to do with `instance`?  Since you don't know the type of your list's contents, probably the best thing you could do would be to cast `instance` as an `IList` so that you could have something other than just an `object`:

```
// Now you have a list - it isn't strongly typed but at least you
// can work with it and use it to some degree.
var instance = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
```

Comment: +1 for `typeof(List<>)`, I hadn't seen this before.

Comment: does `var` exist in .Net framework 2.0?!

Comment: @sprocketonline: `var` is a C# 3 feature so if you are using C# 2 you will need to declare your variables explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me a lot. Exact what I need (I am building expression for EF)

Answer (score 11):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  IList list = foobar(typeof(string));
  list.Add("foo");
  list.Add("bar");
  foreach (string s in list)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private static IList foobar(Type t)
{
  var listType = typeof(List<>);
  var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(t);
  var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
  return (IList)instance;
}
```

Comment: +1 for remember the good old non generic supported interfaces :)

Comment: The same trick works for `IDictionary` :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `MakeGenericType` for such operations.

For documentation, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx).