# How to create specific list type whose parameter is known at runtime and then loop through this list?

Tags: c#, reflection

I know I can create an object whose type is known only at run time like this:

```
Type t = record.GetType();
var src = Activator.CreateInstance(t.BaseType);
```

1. How can I do something like `List<Record>=new List<Record>()` at run time?
2. Suppose I am getting Child Record list using Reflection like this

   `var ChildRecorList=src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);`

and how can then I loop through this using `foreach` or `for` loop because `foreach` only works for known type list. It does now work with var types. Is there way to cast Reflection value to cast at specific type whose value is known at runtime(mentioned in point 1)

Comment: Use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) instead of var if using .Net 4.0 or higher.

Comment: So you know it is going to be a list, because you want to loop over it. Why do you want to create the object via reflection?

Comment: @ Rohit Vats i am using 4.0.Is we can loop using dynamic??i think we cant??

Comment: @RvdK i need this becouse i have many database field i.e 500 and i dont want to map them manually??Yes this would be list.

Comment: Your question is very similar to this one: [C# instantiate generic List from reflected Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661211/c-sharp-instantiate-generic-list-from-reflected-type). There's a good answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to create generic type in runtime:

```
Type genericListType = typeof (List<>);

// if you have more than one generic argumens 
// you can add your types here like typeof(MyClass),typeof(MyClass2)
Type[] genericArguments = { typeof (Record) }; 

// create your generic type with generic arguments
Type myGenericType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(genericArguments);

// and then  you can create your instance
var recordList = Activator.CreateInstance(myGenericType);

// get your property value

recordList = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
```

And I guess you sure your type is a List then when you creating your instance you can make a cast like this:

```
 var recordList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(myGenericType);
```

Then you can loop through your list

```
foreach (var item in recordList)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats realy great...it has worked for me after some addation and modification according to me requirement..Thanks a lot @Selman22

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If you're looking for something like this, But you can use List Inside another List or Dictionary, Also, You can store the base value with any type and get the type whenever needed, I recommend using Dictionary so that way you can name your lists:

```
Dictionary<String, List<Object>> Data = new Dictionary<String, List<Object>>();

Data["MyUser"] = new List<Object>();
Data["MyUser"].Add(MyDBObject);

var obj = Data["MyUser"].Find(x => x.MyKey == "MyKeyObject");
var t = obj.GetType();
var dta = (MyDBObject)obj;

foreach (var db in Data)
{
   if (db.Key == "MyUser")
      db.Value.Find(x => x.Name == "MyName");
}
```

Or If you're looking for Creating lists on runtime:

```
List<List<Object>> Data = new List<List<Object>>();

var mydb = Data.Count;

Data.Add(new List<Object>());

Data[mydb].Add(MyOBJ);

foreach (var db in Data)
{
     if (db.Contains(MyOBJ)
         return db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use generics? You could do something like this:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T type)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
}
```

This will allow you to create a list from whichever type is passed in at runtime.