# How to convert type known at runtime to a List of given type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a type that I only get to know at a runtime:

```
Type givenType = FindOutTypeOf(someObject);
```

and I have following method:

`public void SomeMethod(Type type);`

that I need to call it with the `List<givenType>` type.

How to convert a given type (that I got to know at runtime) to a list of a given type?

Comment: you mean how to create a list of given type? if so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661211/c-sharp-instantiate-generic-list-from-reflected-type

Comment: No, I need to pass the Type (C# class) which is a list of a given type that I retrieved. I'll change the var to Type in the questions

Comment: hmm, well your answer is still  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4661237/3010968) you just don't need to call `Activator.CreateInstance`, `constructedListType` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you change the signature of SomeMethod?

Comment: So for example if `givenType` is `typeof(string)`, then you need to call `SomeMethod` with `typeof(List<string>)`?

Comment: Yup, it's just that I don't know what type (string in your example) is going to be at runtime

Comment: Updated my answer below with corrected code to better address your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var listType = typeof(List<>);
var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(givenType);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, what you are asking cannot be done in a strongly typed language in an generic and elegant fashion.

Think of it this way:
If [someobject](/questions/tagged/someobject) can be literally anything, including types generated at run time, the you cannot create a strongly typed List where t is the typeof([someobject](/questions/tagged/someobject)).

If you do not expect any types generated at runtime, I would try refactoring your solution to use generic types. If for whatever reason you need to do custom operations for each type, you can always abstract the common logic in a base class and them create a derived type where you can implement custom logic for that type.

If this does not suit your needs, you can use the [dynamic](/questions/tagged/dynamic) keyword that C# offers, but this does not guarantee type safety and you can get runtime exceptions.