# Define list before without the type C#

Tags: c#

I would like to initiate the list and depending on some value make this list with a special type which is a model that I create. I don't know if I explained it very well - my code is below

```
public static List<someModeltypeAorBorC> SomeMethod()
{
    var list = new List<dynamic>();
    if (Val == "A")
    {
        List<ModelA> list = new List<ModelA>();
    }
    else if (Val == "B")
    {
        List<ModelB> list = new List<ModelB>();
    }
    else if (Val == "C")
    {
        List<ModelC> list = new List<ModelC>();
    }
}
```

I want to initialize the list outside the scope so that I can use in the next steps. Also as you can see, I have to return this List. Is it possible? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Make `ModelA`,`ModelB`,`ModelC` inherit from a base class `someModeltypeAorBorC` or let them implement the same interface. Another way was to use generics.

Comment: you might want to look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661211/c-sharp-instantiate-generic-list-from-reflected-type

Comment: `List<dynamic>` doesn't mean what you think it means. It just means `List<object>` where we do dynamic binding on the members of the collection. There's no way in C# to represent the notion of "a list of something specific but I'm not saying what something is until runtime".

Comment: Also C# does not support union or intersection types, like "A or B or C". Some languages do. C# is not one of them.

Comment: More generally, what you're trying to do is wrong in C# and is an abuse of generics. Generics in C# are supposed to be *generic*. If you have three possible constructions of a generic then it is not *generic*. Just make three methods, one that returns a `List<A>`, one that returns a `List<B>` and so on. Find a different solution; this one will take you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You all for answer. What I finally did was creating the class Model which other classes Model A.B and C inherits from. Inside the method im adding the line

```
   List<Model> list = new List<Model>();
```

I return List and when i need to reach the properties of the lower class, I am using

```
List<Model> obj = List<Model>; 
obj = SomeMethod() //which return object of ModelA.B or C
((ModelA)obj).PropoertyOfModelA // reach the property specified model
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it:

```
static List<T> CreateList<T>(T value) {
  var list = new List<T>();
  list.Add(value);
  return list;
}
var list = CreateList(
   new{Name="Krishna",  Phones = new[] {"555-555-5555", "666-666-6666"}} );
```